# Breaking a loop whilst in GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interrupt, keyboardinterrupt

I am using a while loop to power an LED at regular intervals. I want to run the loop as normal, but have it break and clean up when a key is pressed.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Where should I add a keyboard interrupt command?

Comment: What is a key, in your case ? Is it a button on a GPIO pin ?

Answer (score 0):

Well <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> raises [KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt). So, you just need to catch it:

```
while True:
    try:
        #code
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

To catch all other errors use:

```
except Exception as ex :  # catch other exceptions #
        print(ex)
```

So, applied to your code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    try:
        GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except Exception as ex :  # catch other exceptions #
        print(ex)
```